# how to use newly declared column in the function?

Tags: sql-server

I need to get output for Cnt<6 values only...can I get them without inserting them into a new table.

**SQL Query**

```
(SELECT t3.State_Name,
          t2.Customer_Name,
          sum(t1.Qty) AS qty,(CASE
                                  WHEN (row_number()OVER (PARTITION BY t3.state_name
                                                          ORDER BY t3.state_name DESC)<6)
                              END)'Cnt'
   FROM t1
   JOIN T2 ON (t1.customer_code=t2.customer_code)
   JOIN t3 ON (t3.Area_code=t1.Area_code)
   WHERE Cnt<6
   GROUP BY State_Name,
            Customer_Name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many examples and answers on here describing how to retrieve the first n rows in a group using `row_number()`.

It would help to know what you are trying to achieve with `...WHERE Cnt < 6`.

If, as it seems, you are trying to retrieve the first six entries for each country, then you want to put your query in a sub-select as the row_number() result cannot be accessed in a `WHERE` clause int he same query; do something like this...

```
SELECT t.State_Name,
       t.Customer_Name,
       t.qty
FROM
(
    SELECT  t3.State_Name,
            t2.Customer_Name,
            sum(t1.Qty) AS qty,
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t3.state_name ORDER BY t3.state_name DESC) AS Cnt
    FROM t1 
    INNER JOIN T2 ON t1.customer_code = t2.customer_code
    INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.Area_code = t1.Area_code
    GROUP BY State_Name,Customer_Name 
) t 
WHERE Cnt < 6
```

However, this will not give you the six states with the highest quantities nor will it give you the six customers with the highest quantities in each state. In either case ordering by the same column as the partitioning column will give you non-deterministic results; you will need to change the `ORDER BY` on the `row_number()` function to use `sum(qty)`.

For the latter just change the `ORDER BY`...

```
SELECT t.State_Name,
       t.Customer_Name,
       t.qty
FROM
(
    SELECT  t3.State_Name,
            t2.Customer_Name,
            sum(t1.Qty) AS qty,
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t3.state_name ORDER BY sum(t1.Qty) DESC) AS Cnt
    FROM t1 
    INNER JOIN T2 ON t1.customer_code = t2.customer_code
    INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.Area_code = t1.Area_code
    GROUP BY State_Name,Customer_Name 
) t 
WHERE Cnt < 6
```

For the former you will also need to remove the `PARTITION BY`...

```
SELECT t.State_Name,
       t.Customer_Name,
       t.qty
FROM
(
    SELECT  t3.State_Name,
            t2.Customer_Name,
            sum(t1.Qty) AS qty,
            row_number() OVER (ORDER BY sum(t1.Qty) DESC) AS Cnt
    FROM t1 
    INNER JOIN T2 ON t1.customer_code = t2.customer_code
    INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.Area_code = t1.Area_code
    GROUP BY State_Name,Customer_Name 
) t 
WHERE Cnt < 6
```